# how to find the file inside input element html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file-io

i was trying to upload a file via $.ajax call using jQuery.. and formData

in order to append the file to the formData i did the following:

```
var fd = new formData();
fd.append($('#myFileInput));
```

that failed

then i tried :

```
var fd = new formData();
fd.append($('#myFileInput).files[0]);
```

and again it failed 
then i tried:

```
var fd = new formData();
fd.append($('#myFileInput')[0].files[0]);
```

and that really worked and i could send my file to the server..

my question is:

why should I use the [0] next to the jquery object representing my file input element.. ??
notice that i didn't use the "multiple" attribute for the file input

Comment: FYI, the other lines were missing the closing '.

Comment: sorry for that typo... but it wasn't missing the closing in the origional code

Comment: and was it $('myFileInput') or $('.myFileInput') ? Notice the .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('selector') returns a jQuery object, and "files" attribute belongs to the DOM object, thus you will need to retrieve the DOM object via $('selector')[0] or $('selector').get(0).